# Unable to connect to VPN via 3G vodafone dongle

Tags: windows-7

Im having trouble to connect to my office VPN when i use my Vodafone dongle. I can connect to VPN through other company dongles & through my home wifi.

Through my searches i found that Vodafone has put your 3G connection behind NAT which could interfere with VPN.

Any fix for this.

Comment: Please supply more information about your VPN, as NAT shouldn't be a problem always. I think your VPN server is listening for INCOMING connections on the specified port, and you are connecting to that port. This should be handled with by NAT, it's like accessing a web page where you connect to a web-server listening to INCOMING connections on port 80. What kind of VPN is this (PPTP, OpenVPN, TINC, L2TP/IPSec, etc)?

Comment: Its a PPTP,but i can connect to my company VPN through other sources but not through that Vodafone dongle

Answer (score 1):

If your VPN in PPTP, then it relays on two protocols:

- TCP traffic on server port 1723 (by default), just for control connection
- IP GRE (protocol 47), for the data flow

Analyzing your particular issue, it means that Vodafone refuses to forward GRE protocol which is a must for any PPTP VPN. There is no direct workaround for that. You should call Vodafone support and ask if they can enable GRE(protocol 47) forwarding on your account.

However you could also try to use another type of VPN to connect to your office network, OpenVPN is a very good open-source alternative, it's very flexible and can be configured to adapt to almost every specific network topology and NAT restrictions.

P.S: for a PPTP VPN, simple NAT/MASQUERADING should not be an issue, but blocking or not forwarding GRE packets is a big one.

P.S2: it could also be Vodafone's fault for firewalling/limiting connections to certain ports/services. In some countries carriers usually block: SMTP, VPN, Online Anonymity application, as an over-protective security measure.